# With QueryDSL, how do you create an expression on a collection where the sub-items match all criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

Assume I have an `Appointment` table and a `Person` table, where an `Appointment` has many `Person`s.

If I wanted to find all Appointments containing *at least one* Person in my list I would do:

```
Collection<Person> personsList = getInterestedPersons();
BooleanExpresssion expr = appointment.persons.any().in(personsList)
```

However, what I really want to so is find all Appointments that have ALL the persons in my list.

So, how can I construct a `BooleanExpression` that will let me filter for all Appointments who have all the Persons?

Note: I must create a BooleanExprsesion, because this is part of a larger generic filter for Appointments, where all the BooleanExpressions get and()ed together.

Another note, I do not what to find Appointments that have *only* those Persons, just at *least all* those in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I guess the following should work:

```
BooleanBuilder personClause = new BooleanBuilder();
for (Person person : personList)
{
    personClause.and(appointment.persons.contains(person));
}
query.where(personClause); // to add the clause
```